# On the square values of a certain polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, perfect-squares

> Consider the following polynomial on two variables: $$P(a,b)=a^4-4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4.$$ Do positive integers $x$ and $y$ exist such that $P(x,y)$ is a perfect square?

I'm aware that this may be actually a very hard problem in disguise, since I'm trying to prove something that I'm not aware that has been proven yet by using this as a lemma, and since this is number theory after all. However, the striking resemblance of this polynomial to $(a\pm b)^4$ and the fact that its homogeneous make me believe there may be a not-so-hard way to prove/disprove this conjecture. I've tried to limit the expression between two consecutive squares, I've tried module  and I even tried to gather some evidence: No solutions with $$10000>a>b$$ exist. Is there something I'm missing? Can more heavy machinery be used?

Comment: >Implying MSE will solve this problem.

Comment: @AlfredYerger You're here too? I can't believe it - you're truly everywhere...

Answer (score 4):

Try to use $$a^4-4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4=(a^2-2ab-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2.$$
Now, we can assume $(a,b)=1$ and there are $m$ and $n$ with different parity such that $(m,n)=1$

for which  $a^2-2ab-b^2=m^2-n^2$ and $ab=mn$.

Comment: Followed maybe by a substitution? I feel like this is a very vague lead.

Comment: @ Anonymous P Now we can assume that $(a,b)=1$ and there are $m$ and $n$ with $(m,n)=1$ and different  parity for which $ab=mn$ and $a^2-2ab-b^2=m^2-n^2$.

Comment: I suspect that what Michael has in mind is that in order for $P(a,b)$ to be a square value, the rewrite above puts it into the much smaller category of a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), as also the sum of two square values.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO - the only integer solutions involve $a=0$ or $b=0$.

The quartic is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
\begin{equation}
v^2=u^3+3u^2+u
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{u+v}{u+1}
\end{equation}

Using Pari-GP's inbuilt elliptic curve functions and Denis Simon's ellrank software, it is straightforward to show that the only rational points on the curve are $(0,0)$ and $(-1, \pm 1)$. These only lead to $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: What is "birational equivalence"? I think I can understand how the rest works.

Comment: @Allan: Can you kindly look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587582/solving-x4y4z4-t2-via-elliptic-curves) involving elliptic curves?